# form submitting when information is incorrect/not entered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't want my form to submit if the user has not entered information or has entered incorrectly. When I hit the submit button however it submits it. I have some code in the javascript that is supposed to do this. I copied it from another form validation but it is not working in mine.

this is what I added for the submit button:

```
var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');

submitButton.onclick = function(){
    var nameIsValid = checkName();
    var emailIsValid = checkEmail();
    var passwordIsValid = checkPassword();

    var valid = nameIsValid && emailIsValid && passwordIsValid;

    // stop default action if valid still equals false
    return valid;
}
```

you can view my full code in my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pXLPv/

Comment: You should handle `form`'s `onsubmit` event instead of `submit button`'s `click` event.

Comment: Just `return` the validation function call on submit, like this: `<form action="" onsubmit="return checkValidation();">`

Answer (score 0):

I always include the check routine in the onSubmit for the `<form>` itself e.g.

```
<form method=get action="formhandler.asp" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);">
```

This has the advantage of giving you scope as well, and I don't have to stuff around with retrospective assignment.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change your button type to **Button**. Because of i believe your default form submission take place and **Submit** Click event is not working as you want.

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Or you can also use form submit event of Javascript. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/NBR5H/)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/pXLPv/1/)

Comment: It wasn't me but you were probably downvoted because that either didn't solve the problem or your competition is trying to discredit you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using JQuery and the Validator plugin. The main advantage of JQuery is the preventDefault() method, which stops the button from firing as it is supposed to. Using the Validator, you would check if the form is valid and if it is, submit the form. You can use AJAX too, in this way. If the form is not valid, you would return instant feedback. I can post an example later once I am off my phone.

Comment: Hi yes I would love to but my assignment requires javascript unfortunately :(

Comment: JQuery is JS. It is a framework that makes life easier. In the case that you cannot use JQuery, I would follow advice to return the validator click onSubmit (from the form) (as above by @hector or @karlen).

Answer (score 0):

Change you submit `button` type to Button.

```
<input type="button" id="btn_id" value="Submit"/>
```

Then use jQuery as

```
$('#btn_id').click(function(){
    var nameIsValid = checkName();
    var emailIsValid = checkEmail();
    var passwordIsValid = checkPassword();

    var valid = nameIsValid && emailIsValid && passwordIsValid;

    if(!valid)
    {
        alert('Invalid Fields');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#form_id').submit();
    }
});
```